# Trouble targeting nth-child in an Ember app

Tags: css, ember.js, css-selectors

I'm working on an Ember app, and have to target nth-child using the wrong numbers, because of the Ember script tags. Is there a reliable way to target nth-children with CSS in an Ember app?

So, instead of:

```
.league li:nth-child(1) h3::after { color: #eec600; }
.league li:nth-child(2) h3::after { color: #b0b0b0; }
.league li:nth-child(3) h3::after { color: #ae7435; }
```

I have to do:

```
.league li:nth-child(3) h3::after { color: #eec600; }
.league li:nth-child(6) h3::after { color: #b0b0b0; }
.league li:nth-child(9) h3::after { color: #ae7435; }
```

Comment: The "wrong" numbers? You mean odd? Check out `div:nth-child(odd) {...}`

Comment: Nearly 4k and you still don't include some code snippets for such a question? ... Use [`:nth-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-of-type) ...

Comment: @NicoO In a hurry - snippet added :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `:nth-of-type()` to filter out the script tags.

If you need to use `nth-child()` then you should use [Ember.js 1.8.0-beta](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/beta)

Ember.js 1.8.0-beta no longer inserts script tags into the dom so you should have no problems using `nth-child()`.

If you are using `ember-cli` you can run `bower install ember#1.8.0-beta.3 --save` to use the beta in your project